# firebase storage: changing folder (file path)'s name with gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

```
gsutil mv gs://bucket/gamelists/ gs://bucket/games/
```

I have folders of media files inside the `gamelists` and want to rename the folder to `games`. I did the following command and it did not change anything.

Is there any way that I can just change the main folders?

Comment: The documentation suggests you do not use trailing slashes. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#renaming-groups-of-objects

Comment: omg. I totally missed that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested and referred , by Doug Stevenson in the comment above please follow recommendations to prevent the issue.
The gsutil mv command allows you to move data between your local file system and the cloud, move data within the cloud, and move data between cloud storage providers.

You can use the gsutil mv command to rename all objects with a given prefix to have a new prefix.

`gsutil mv gs://my_bucket/oldprefix gs://my_bucket/newprefix`

If you have a large number of files to move you might want to use the gsutil -m option, to perform a multi-threaded/multi-processing move:

`gsutil -m mv gs://my_bucket/oldprefix gs://my_bucket/newprefix`

[Reference Document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#renaming-groups-of-objects)